# Calculate sum of each row using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable of below columns

```
Price1  Price2  Price3  Price4  ColSum
------  ------  ------  ------  ------
2.5 4.7     8       99          
10  39      88.3    90  
99  21      33      3.2
```

Now, how do I calculate sum of each row using LINQ?

I want to achieve

```
ColSum = sum(Price1+Price2+Price3+Price4)
```

for each columns by linq.

Comment: Do you want to do that for each row? or you want only one value as a total for all the table?

Comment: are you after `Obj.AsEnumerable().Sum(obj=>obj.Price);` ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need Linq at all; simply use the [`Expression` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Gets or sets the expression used to filter rows, calculate the values in a column, or create an aggregate column.

**Example:**

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Price1", typeof(decimal));
dt.Columns.Add("Price2", typeof(decimal));
dt.Columns.Add("Price3", typeof(decimal));
dt.Columns.Add("Price4", typeof(decimal));
dt.Columns.Add("ColSum", typeof(decimal));

dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{2.5, 4.6, 8, 99});
dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{10, 39, 88.3, 90});
dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{99, 21, 33, 3.2});

dt.Columns["ColSum"].Expression = "Price1+Price2+Price3+Price4";
```

`dt` now looks like:

[image]

This way, you can keep your `DataTable` and the `ColSum` column is automatically updated for you.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

You just want the sum of each row in a calculated member?

```
var result = myTable.AsEnumerable().Select(r =>
                     new {
                         Price1 = r.Price1,
                         Price2 = r.Price2,
                         Price3 = r.Price3,
                         Price4 = r.Price4,
                         ColSum = r.Price1 + r.Price2 + r.Price3 + r.Price4
                     });
```

Comment: Yes, but its gives "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type" exception

Comment: @Avijit - yes you're in a `DataTable` which only has the `Select(string)` method. Convert it to an Enumerable using `.AsEnumerable()` - see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sums = Prices.Select(i => new { ColSum= i.Price1 + i.Price2 + i.Price3 + i.Price4 });

foreach (var sum in sums)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sum.ColSum.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var sum = objectList.Select(i => new
                {
                    Sum = i.Price1 + i.Price2+i.Price3+i.Price4
                });
```

With the data table

```
 var result = from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
                        select new
                        {
                            Sum = p.Field<double>("Price1") + p.Field<double>("Price2") + p.Field<double>("Price3") + p.Field<double>("Price4")
                        };
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you?

Comment: I was just criticizing your choice of a name *ObjectList*. I don't think you want to use a singleton (which would be horrible, horrible design), or that you're trying to use the ObjectList class, so the name should start with a lower-case letter, unless I'm missing something. That being said, good day to you.

Comment: @ArlaudPierre: oh sorry, didn't got in first place :) updated now!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var result = from p in priceList
             select new 
                    {
                       Price1 = p.Price1,
                       Price2 = p.Price2,
                       Price3 = p.Price3,
                       Price4 = p.Price4, 
                       ColSum = p.Price1 + p.Price2 + p.Price3 + p.Price4 + p.Price5
                     };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through columns collection for each row:

```
int sum;
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            sum = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Sum(column => Convert.ToInt32(row[column]));
            MessageBox.Show("Sum for current row: " + sum);
        }
```